# Map with String key where value is array of pair of longs in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, dictionary, multidimensional-array, long-integer

I am fighting with Javascript data structures. I need to create a map where the key is a string and the value is an array of two longs.

For example, something like:

```
var x = myMap["SomeString"];

var firstLong = x[0][0];
var secondLong = x[0][1];

// do something with first and second long

firstLong = x[1][0];
secondLong = x[1][1];

// do something with first and second long

etc..
```

How do can I achieve this properly in Javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by `long`?

Comment: Something that can contain timestamps (milliseconds since the epoch)

Comment: @JVerstry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON has more information

Comment: what is "array of two longs" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in order to work with multidimensional arrays, you need first to "define" the dimensions, i.e.

```
var myMap = {};
myMap["SomeString"] = [];

myMap["SomeString"][0] = [];   // new dimension
myMap["SomeString"][0][0] = 1; // can be also done with
myMap["SomeString"][0][1] = 2; // myMap["SomeString"][0].push(2);

myMap["SomeString"][1] = [];   // new dimension
myMap["SomeString"][1][0] = 3;
myMap["SomeString"][1][1] = 4;
```

The same can be done with literal:

```
var myMap = {
    SomeString: [
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4]
    ]
};

console.log(myMap["SomeString"][0][1]);  // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

dictionary equivalent data structure in javascript is basic JavaScript object . you can try

```
var myMap = {

    SomeString : [
        [1,2],
        [32222,44444]
    ]
}
```

and for print them

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't actually mean a 2d array;

```
var myMap = {};
myMap["SomeString"] = [123, 456];

alert( myMap["SomeString"][0] );
alert( myMap["SomeString"][1] );
```

Comment: Yes I do, the returned array is an array of int/long pairs